# Refresh a function every 3 seconds in react native

Tags: react-native, setinterval

I was wondering if it is okay to set the time interval to trigger a function every 3 seconds. Let's say I have 5 different screens in my application and all 5 screens have the time interval set to 3 seconds and will keep on calling a function to auto refresh the screen.

My concern is, will it cause a heavy traffic to the server if there are multiple users using the app at the same time and the server will keep on receiving the request from the app?

**Sample code :**

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.loadCase()
    }, 3000);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}

loadCase(){
    CaseController.loadCase().then(data=>{
        if(data.status == true){
            this.setState({ case: data.case })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just refresh when the user requests to? Or websockets for realtime data

Answer (score 0):

If you have an API endpoint that you need to poll every 3 seconds and you're looking to avoid redundant calls from the app, try using `setInterval` in your App.js, or wherever the root of your app is, and dump the result into Redux/whatever state management solution you're using so that you can access it elsewhere.

To answer your question regarding "heavy traffic," yeah, that is inevitably going to be a lot of API calls that your server will need to handle. If it's going to cause issues with the current setup of your API server, I would look closely at your app and see if there's a way you can reduce the effects that large numbers of users will have, whether that's some sort of caching, or increasing the amount of time between API calls, or entirely reconsidering this approach.